# Why doesn't the following code update the database?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to update the contents of my database using bootstrap modal form with ajax code.but my database does not get updated with the inputs provided in the form. the form works perfectly fine but i don't see the contents updated in the database. what is wrong ??? please help as i searched whole internet and got nothing :(

**html code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1> {{ username }} </h1>
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
  <form id="new_user_form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group"  >
              <label for="usr">Username:</label>
              <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control input-lg" id="username">
              <label for="passwordd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-sm" id="password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap 3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Ajax code:**

```
<script>
 $(document).on('submit','#new_user_form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/testapp/registered/",
            data: {
                    username: $('#username').val(),
                    password: $('#password').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            sucess: function(){
                alert("Registeration successfully.")
            }
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
    });
});


</script>
```

**views.py :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from testapp.models import User

def index(request):
    template = 'index.html'
    return render(request,template)

def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        User.objects.create(
            username = request.POST['username'],
            password = request.POST['password'],
        )
        User.save()
    return render(request,'testapp/index.html',{'username':request.POST['username']})
```

**testapp\urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="Index"),
    url(r'^registered/$', views.create_user, name="registered"),
]
```

Comment: have you test to debug with ipdb in your `create_user` views? what you get if you call `request.POST` ?

Comment: what is ipdb ? well i created  a copy of my main project and guess what that copy did updated the database but the main project still not updating the database and i did an inspect on both of the projects and i got 500 internal server error here is the image of the error : https://postimg.org/image/tim44b9nl/

Comment: Most likely `User.save()` is causing the error. Because the class `User` has no attribute save. Just get rid of that line. the `create` already saves the object for you

Comment: @karthikr that is not right " User " does have a save function i can see it in the suggestions. well now i don't get any 500 internal server error but the form doesn't get closed automatically (  after submitting ) and i don't get an alert message saying "Registration Successfully!" ( that i have written in Ajax code in success label )

Comment: Okay i solved the alert message problem but the form is not closing automatically

Answer (score 0):

Only do this:

```
my_user = User.objects.create(username=request.POST['username'], password = request.POST['password'] )
my_user.save()
```

You need to save created instance of model not just call .save() function of model.

Answer (score -1):

in testapp\urls.py: swap the url routing logic

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^registered/$', views.create_user, name="registered"),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="Index")
]
```